# Which date comparison is more efficient when searching in a day in a time range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, casting

When querying a table to fetch data by a single day I found 2 options.

Let say I want to fetch all data of 2020-01-01 and the date column called "CreatedDate" which is a datetime.

My "WHERE" can be :

```
Where CreatedDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-02'
```

However I started using the following format:

```
Where CAST(CreatedDate as date) = '2020-01-01'
```

I found the 2 option more "friendly" since I'm comparing to  single value which is more readable.

I wonder if the format, which requires casting , might cost in more computing resources and will increase the query wight?

Comment: Compare the execution plans.

Comment: All discussed in detail [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). And you should have sufficient experience by now to know that you should ALWAYS identify the version and edition you are using since functionality varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do different things.  The first gets the data at midnight on 2020-01-02.  The eequivalent logic is:

```
where CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01' and
      CreatedDate < '2020-01-02'
```

As for your question, you should test the two versions on your data and your system.  Both version will use an index on `(CreatedDate)` because SQL Server allows the use of an index for conversion to dates.  From the perspective of using indexes, they are equivalent.

That said, without an index, there might be a slight overhead for the date conversion, so the second version might be a little bit slower in that case.

Comment: I tested it on exuction plan and indeed the 1st one when I use from- to range was slightly more effective.
about 1.35 sec compare to 1.55 when casting to date.

Thanks.